# How to select a link which contains a particular text in its deeper level ? Selenium - Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have a list and I need to select an item from the list according to its text using Selenium Webdriver.
But the text is located a few level deeper from the link. 
How can I click that link after I find the "Target Text" ?

[image]

I could able to find The "Target Text" with the code below.

```
var dir = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//*[contains(text(), '{0}')]", path.Directory)));
```

But I think I need to click a link. How can I go up to tag "a" from "Target Text"?

Comment: What is the problem, which part are you struggling with?

Comment: My purpose is to click the link just above the "Target Text". But the trick is here, my guide is only the target text. So I need to find it first which I did already and then go up to first link above it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **/..** in xpath 1 time to reach on parent **anchor** node with the help of **text**. Try below code.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(), 'Target Text')]/.."));
```

Comment: This does not find anything unfortunately, driver.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//span[contains(text(), '{0}')]", path.Directory)));

Comment: Why do you use //span at the beginning of the XPaht? Meanwhile I am just working with selenium for a few days.

Comment: When I use this, It goes to the "html" tag. { driver.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//*[contains(text(), '{0}')]/../..", path.Directory))); }

Comment: Target text is unique or multiple on page? Span is for reaching on text node then move from there to parent node a. I have updated answer. Try now. I did a mistake.

Comment: It does not work too, maybe because of the link that I am trying to find in a popup window.

Comment: Okay then you have to switch on pop up window first.

Comment: Please try after switch to new pop window

Answer (score 0):

```
var dir = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//*[contains(text(), '{0}')]/ancestor::a[1]", path.Directory)));
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: The link that I am trying to find in a popup window, does it required an additional operation?

Comment: it captures the element by text first as explained in question, from that element it travels to the immediate ancestor of <a> element.

Comment: link element in the popup window means you have to first switch to the popup window, try something like this ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());        
 driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));